# SQL query to pull out weight: eg 249kg from comments text field

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

i would like to pull into a view  some numbers and text from a comments field within SQL Server.

The comments field displays (Weight: 249kg) but i will only need the 249kg

What query could pull this information as will need a little more than '%[0-9]%'

Thanks

Comment: For that exact string, in T-SQL, you could use `REPLACE(Field,'Weight: ','')` but I'm guessing there are more permutations. Why don't you show us some others and also tell us what kind of database (SQL Server? Oracle?)

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide several examples of the complete comment string.  (3) Explain what to do if there are no weights are multiple weights.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`, it looks a bit messy but should work

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(value1 VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES('Weight: 249KG');

SELECT value1
FROM @table;


SELECT SUBSTRING
       (value1, CHARINDEX
       (':', value1)+1, CHARINDEX('KG', value1)-CHARINDEX(':', value1)-1) AS value1
FROM @table;
```

Returns:
`Weight: 249KG`
and
`249`

**EDIT:**

I miss read, I thought you just wanted the number rather than the unit after i.e. `249` rather than `249KG`. you can use `REPLACE` for that like:

```
SELECT REPLACE(value1,'Weight: ','') FROM @table
```

Comment: that seems like it would work, at the moment i' am having little trouble putting the query together. Here are the tables i' am selecting and it's the dbo.JobOper.CommentText where i need the pull value from 

SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.JobOper.JobNum, dbo.LaborDtl.ClockInDate, dbo.JobOper.CommentText, dbo.JobOper.OpCode, dbo.JobOper.QtyCompleted, 
dbo.JobOper.JobComplete
FROM dbo.LaborDtl RIGHT OUTER JOIN
  dbo.JobOper ON dbo.LaborDtl.Company = dbo.JobOper.Company AND dbo.LaborDtl.JobNum = dbo.JobOper.JobNum
WHERE     (dbo.JobOper.OpCode LIKE 'QF-saw')
ORDER BY dbo.JobOper.JobNum

Comment: why are you using top 100 percent? and which do you want to use? substring or replace?

Comment: i wish to pull this out in to a view not replace or edit anything.

Comment: Change your select to either `REPLACE (dbo.JobOper.CommentText, 'Weight: ',''),` or `SUBSTRING
        (dbo.JobOper.CommentText, CHARINDEX
        (':', dbo.JobOper.CommentText)+1, CHARINDEX('KG', dbo.JobOper.CommentText)-CHARINDEX(':', dbo.JobOper.CommentText)-1) AS CommentText,` depending on the method you want to use